# Alternative products compatible with LEGO

Tags: patent

I heard that lately a [patent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRwhY.jpg) for LEGO expired and now everyone can create a company to produce bricks that are compatible with LEGO.

I am wondering how many of such companies are there.

I know one from my country, [Cobi](https://cobi.pl/en/). Can you point me another alternatives?

Comment: This should really be broken up into questions along the lines of "Is X compatible with Lego?" or "Can I make X compatible with Lego?" Otherwise we will get each answer containing overlapping subsets, and we'll likely miss good advice on specific adapters or techniques. In general, we should _not_ be seeking CW questions or answers at this point in the site's lifetime.

Comment: There are many different patents. The ones for the original bricks expired long ago, as patents expire after 20 years.

Comment: I agree with Joe; there's no one set of correct answers.  It's a wiki-type question, and is too early for this site.

Comment: This other SE question is relevant to the patent part : "Are companies producing custom molded LEGO pieces legally entitled to do so?" : http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/250/are-companies-producing-custom-molded-lego-pieces-legally-entitled-to-do-so

Comment: I think Joe's got the right idea... As appealing as One Big List might seem, questions on individual products are probably a *lot* more useful to folks researching the products available to them.

Answer (score 12):

there are at least:

- [KRE-O](http://www.hasbro.com/kre-o/en_US/) (not sure if this is compatible in size, but it looks exactly like LEGO)
- [Enlighten](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/enlighten.htm)
- [Best-Lock](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/bestlock.htm)
- [Blockmen](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/blockmen.htm) (out of production)
- [Cobi](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/cobi.htm) (wich you already listed)
- [SuperBlox](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/crazartsuperblox.htm)
- [iDol](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/idol.htm)
- [Kazi](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/kazi.htm) (looks like poor quality)
- [Sluban](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/sluban.htm) (out of production)
- [Mega Blocks](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/megabloks.htm)
- [Super Blocks](http://my-clone-bricks.webs.com/tycosuperblocks.htm) (out of production)
- [Custom-Crazy](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/02/custom-crazy-overview/)
- [Sidan Toys](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/02/sidan-toys-overview/)
- [Arealight](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/09/lcustom-lego-star-wars-from-arealight/)
- [Brickforge](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/10/brickforge-secret/)
- [Christo](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/07/lego-customs-by-christo/)
- [BrickWarriors](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/09/brickwarriors-custom-lego/)
- [Oxford](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/07/oxford-toys-overview/)
- [Little Armory](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/06/little-armory-overview/)
- [Nanoblocks](http://www.mynanoblock.com/site/) (not sure, but looks smaller than LEGO, so this might not be compatible)

Note that some of this only produce custom accessories for minifigs, very small sets or exact copies of the official sets, no own really "big" sets like LEGO does

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few:

- [BrickTW](http://www.bricklink.com/store.asp?p=bricktw)
- [Character](http://www.character-online.com/products/Character-Building/) do Dr Who and HM Armed forces themed sets and figures.
- Click Brick
- [HiTechnic](http://www.hitechnic.com/) produce Mindstorms compatible sensors
- [Kids Connection](http://www.instructables.com/id/Comparitive-study-of-studded-construction-bricks/step4/Kids-Connection-storebrand/)
- [K'Nex](http://www.knex.com/Shop/introducing_bricks.php) prduce lego-compatible bricks. Their product can be used to interconnect Lego and K'Nex.
- [ME Models](http://www.me-models.com/store/index.php?cPath=22_57&osCsid=37920e35ec229cbe4b0ab8908c2cd775) sell compatible train tracks.
- M.Y Building Bricks
- [Ritvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkbi_AG_v._Ritvik_Holdings_Inc.) is a former name of [Mega Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Brands)
- [Sploids](http://www.sploids.com/) could be used to link Lego and K'Nex.
- [Tandem Bricks](http://bloks.hyperboards.com/index.php?action=view_topic&topic_id=638)
- [Tatco](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=36294)
- [Toyrific Bricks](http://www.wiltonbradley.com/section.php?xSec=184&jssCart=f9b6805e395b1c52b97371584513cd7a)
- [Tyco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyco_Toys) produced Superblocks

Answer (score 1):

[Brickarms](http://brickarms.com) makes nice custom Lego-compatible weapons, accessories, and minifigures.